# Pre-formatted HTML containing unwanted line-break

Tags: html, pre

I am trying to create a pre-formatted block of text using the `pre` element where there are sometimes a few blank lines in between the content. The problem is that occasionally the text breaks onto a separate line after either a forward slash(/) or colon(:)

An example is as follows:

```
<pre>Lorem ipsum dolor sitat: http://wwww.site.com/foo/bar</pre>
```

Displays as:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sitat: http://wwww.site.com/foo
/bar
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Is it overflowing the container?

Comment: @Kyle Not at the moment coz I have CSS set to "white-space:pre-wrap". It overflows if I set it to "white-space:pre"

Answer (score 0):

I'm with @Kyle, without seeing the page itself I think that it is too long for the container that  you have it in, so maybe make the text smaller or widen the container and see if that helps.

I tried:

```
<html>
<pre>Lorem ipsum dolor sitat: http://wwww.site.com/foo/bar</pre>
</html>
```

and didn't get any line breaks.

Comment: Text is as follows: "It's a crime-reduction measure that's been in use across the tube network for a few years: http://www.site.com (breaks onto new line here even though there's plenty of room to fit rest of URL on) /remainder-of-url.html

Comment: Widening container or making text smaller doesn't resolve problem. It's also not restricted to colons or forward slashes. Sometimes just happens after normal characters

Comment: I tried it and it isn't splitting for me, tried chrome11/firefox4/ie8. Though I also tried putting it in a div to try and force it to break and that didn't either so I'm not quite sure anymore.

Comment: It's hard-coded at the moment to only include my twitter username, but i want to include all spaces to represent the characters a user could've typed in between tweets, based on 3 characters per second. As you see it's always the last word of the tweet that breaks onto another line: http://jsfiddle.net/zZwnh/